# Support for Citus in production? Community or Premium?

Tags: citus

We've been building a system that is using Citus db and we are considering purchasing the premium support option before going into production, however costs are relatively high. My analysis of the community is that is quite small and niche, although there is a growing [slack channel](https://slack.citusdata.com/) and [google groups forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/citus-users).

Our errors experienced during development has been mostly solved through the documentation which is good. Going into prod, there is some uncertainty around configuration hence my question.

Has anyone had any issues and used either the community or premium support? What was the experience like in terms of speed of delivery, quality of responses, consistency of feedback and finally turnaround time to resolve an issue.

Ultimately we need to provide high SLAs to our clients and resolving issues quickly in production is critical to our business

Answer (score 7):

We at [Pex](https://pex.com) use Citus in production for almost two years, running on 20+ worker nodes. We've started on the community version for the first year or so and switched to the premium version couple of months ago.

When we started using citus, we ran into a lot of issues (mostly related to the fact, that citus at that time wasn't as closely compatible with standalone PGSQL as is today, not because of bugs or performance issues). I can't tell if we were the rule or an exception, but the citus team was incredibly supportive, responding within hours to any (stupid) question we had, helping with anything we needed. Thanks to their help we were able to achieve [an incredible scale](https://cloud.google.com/customers/pex/).

Their support is also the main reason why decided to switch to the premium version. The response time is incredible. We have answers within hours, if there is a production breaking problem then minutes. Also one of the reasons we chose citus over other solutions (and we tried many) is the pace of the new releases. Every couple of weeks there is [a new version](https://github.com/citusdata/citus/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) out that fixes all found bugs and adds a lot of new features.

Overall, picking citus was one of the luckiest decision we made as a company.